# Mathematical notation for number of times an element appears in a multiset

Tags: notation, multisets

I have a multiset, say $\{8,5,7,8,8,9,5,5,3,0,1\}$, and I wish to compute a weight with the following formula: number of times an element appears in the multiset divided by the total number of elements in the multiset. For example, if the element is $8$ then the weight becomes $3$ (eight appearing three times) divided by $11$ (the total number of elements in the multiset).

How can I express this formula in mathematical notation using symbols like the sigma (sum) symbol for the number of times an element appears and what should be the symbol for expressing the size of the multiset?

Comment: Please edit the question to tell us why you need a formula. The size of set $A$ is often written as $|A|$ or as $#A$.

Comment: [Multiset](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multiset) is the correct name for this case.

Comment: "The number of times an element belongs to the multiset is the [multiplicity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multiplicity_(mathematics)) of that member."

Comment: @EthanBolker I do not need a formula. I have already mentioned it. It is number of times a number appear in the set divided by set size. I am not sure of how to express it using math symbols. Appreciate your help!

Comment: If $A$ is the set, we define a function $\text {mult}(a) : A \to \mathbb N^+$ such that $\text {mult}(a)$ is the *multiplicity* (a positive number) of $a$, for every $a \in A$. Thus, what you need is $\dfrac { \text {mult}(a) } { |A| }$.

Comment: Rewrite the multiset as $\{ 0^{a_0}, 1^{a_1}, \cdots, n^{a_n} \}$ where $a_i$ denotes the multiplicity of the element $i$. Calculate $A= \sum _{i=0}^{n} a_i$ then the wieghting of the element $i$ is $a_i/A$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, it is not a set: it is a *multiset* (a set does not include multiplicities: $\{1,1,1,1,1,2\} = \{1,2\}$. A multiset does).

A possibility, using the *indicator* $\mathbf{1}$: for a multiset $S$,the number of times $x$ appears in $S$ (the multiplicity of $x$ in $S$) can be written
$$
\sum_{s\in S} \mathbf{1}_{\{x\}}(s)
$$
or
$$
\sum_{s\in S} \mathbf{1}_{\{s=x\}}
$$
(What it means is, literally: sum, over all elements of $S$, of a value which is $1$ if $s=x$ (that is, equivalently, if $s\in\{x\}$) and 0 otherwise).

This is quite standard; at least, I have seen it in numerous occasions (papers and lecture notes). From there, the *frequency* of $x$ in $S$ can be written simply as
$$
\frac{1}{\lvert S\rvert}\sum_{s\in S} \mathbf{1}_{\{x\}}(s)
$$
using again the standard notation $\lvert S\rvert$ for the cardinality of $S$.

Comment: I will go with your answer. Thank you and others for guiding me.

Comment: You're welcome!

Answer (score 2):

As set we would have $A := \{8,5,7,8,8,9,5,5,3,0,1\} = \{0,1,3,5,7,8,9\}$. So what you want to define here is a multiset defined by the function
$$f:A \rightarrow \Bbb N _0,
\begin{cases}
0 \mapsto 1\\
1 \mapsto 1\\
3 \mapsto 1\\
5\mapsto 3\\
7\mapsto 1\\
8\mapsto 3\\
9\mapsto 2
\end{cases}
$$
where $f$ counts how often an element $a\in A$ is in the multiset defined by $f$

Now we can give the formula for a number $a\in A$ you search for by $$\frac{f(a)}{|A|}$$

Answer (score 1):

When an object contains multiple occurrences of the same element it is called a multiset, we sometimes use strong brackets (but generally use normal ones) to differentiate the multiset $\mathcal A$ from its support set $A$.

For instance $\mathcal A=\boldsymbol\{8,5,7,8,8,9,5,5,3,0,1\boldsymbol\}$ would have support set $A=\{8,5,7,9,3,0,1\}$

The multiplicity of an element can be noted $\displaystyle \nu(a)=\#\boldsymbol\{x\in \mathcal A\mid x=a\boldsymbol\}=\sum\limits_{x\in \mathcal A}1_a(x)$

And the cardinality is noted $\displaystyle |\mathcal A|=\#\mathcal A=\sum\limits_{a\in A} \nu(a)$

The function you want is then $\dfrac{\nu(a)}{|A|}$.

---

In general a multiset $\mathcal S=\langle S,\nu\rangle$ is the provision of a set $S$ and a multiplicity function $\nu:S\to\mathbb N$ (with zero).

This is how we perform operations on them like $\mathcal A\cap\mathcal B$, by operations on the multiplicity functions $\nu_{\mathcal A\cap\mathcal B}(x)=\min(\nu_{\mathcal A}(x),\nu_{\mathcal B}(x))$ for all $x\in A\cap B$ for instance.

Note that the definition allow for the multiplicity to be $0$, so the support set $S$ can be somehow "larger" than the canonical support set which would have a strictly positive multiplicity function, for instance $S=\mathbb N$.

When $\nu_{\mathcal A}(x)=0$ then $x\notin\mathcal A$.

This apparent lax in the definition allows in fact to have the same support set for multisets which all have the same "type" of elements and concentrate on the multiplicity functions.

For instance a normal set $A$ of integers could also be identified as $\langle \mathbb N,1_A\rangle$.

Comment: I have never seen the notation with "strong brackets." In which field have you seen it? Do you have references/pointers?

Comment: @ClementC. I should have wrote sometimes rather than often, I agree it is not that such spread notation. But for instance https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multiensemble

Comment: Note that on the French page you link (by the way, I am French and never saw it, but I left after undergrad — conceivable, though, since we didn't do much on multisets back then) it's not **bold** braces, but **double** ones.

Comment: Well, I suspect it should be `\mathbb {`. Anyway, this is a minor matter :D